# sec_api module issue. Python script unable to find it

Tags: python

My script cannot find the `sec_api` module. I have insalled it in the same directory path as my scripts, succesfully requested an API key, and it still does not work. What am I doing wrong? I thought the correct file path and module access would be enough.

```py
from sec_api import QueryApi

queryApi = QueryApi(api_key="YOUR_API_KEY")

query = {
  "query": { "query_string": { 
      "query": "ticker:TSLA AND filedAt:{2020-01-01 TO 2020-12-31} AND formType:\"10-Q\"" 
    } },
  "from": "0",
  "size": "10",
  "sort": [{ "filedAt": { "order": "desc" } }]
}

filings = queryApi.get_filings(query)

print(filings)
```

```py
  File "C:\Users\myusername\OneDrive\Desktop\classes\SP_22_courses\CS1110\pye_files\sec.py", line 7, in <module>
    from sec_api import QueryApi

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sec_api'
```